# fullCalendar resources not showing up

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I have an extraction function that extracts data from a json file in a <script.> function(my extraction code)</script.> and returning it in the format I want, an array of dictionaries [{..}, {..}].  My calendar function at the very beginning looks like:

```
<script>myResources = getJSONdata();
...
```

Then I'm logging it to console so I can see I get it. The console output is:

```
[{...}]
  0:
    title: "First entry"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

I then pass this variable that I just console.log'd to the resources variable

```
resources: myResources
```

Doesn't work. Though it works if I hardcode...

```
resources: [{title: "first entry"}]
```

What is going on here?

Comment: do you have multiple entire or just "First Entry"?

Comment: I will have multiple, but I only have the single entry <{title: First entry}> whilst debugging, which is a dictionary entry in an array of dictionaries.